# После установки OPENCART темы столкнулся с такой проблемой

Tags: php, opencart

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/evitrina/admin/view/template/extension/soconfig/class/soconfig_minifier.php on line 23

```
if(!file_exists($this->path))   mkdir($this->path, 0777, true);
```

Comment: странные права на папку запрашивает) Проверьте права на указанный файл - там скорее всего 644 стоят и поэтому скрипт не может создать директорию

Comment: Да там я для каждого 777 указал даже после этого такая проблема

Comment: а на саму директорию где этот файл создается какие права? Посмотрите чтобы были на запись.